# How will behavior differ if I let VS or VsVim handle all conflicting key bindings?

Tags: vsvim

After installing VsVim, Visual Studio displays a message that there are conflicting key bindings between VsVim and Visual Studio.

I have two options:

- Handle all with VsVim
- Handle all with Visual Studio

and a checkbox:

- Include all scopes

I have googles to find the meanings if these options but have not had success.

My questions are:

- What do the options mean?
- What option do most people choose?

Answer (score 2):

These options decide how key strokes that represent commands in Visual Studio and vim should be handled. Consider keys like `<Ctrl-A>` which typically means:

- Visual Studio: select all
- vim: Increment number under caret

The conflicting key options is helping you set which behavior you want for the keys.

The "include all scopes" checkbox can generally be ignored.